# Do (document) bundle entries always have to be referenced or referencing?

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi

The specification for FHIR documents seems to mandate that all bundle entries in the document resource be part of the reference graph rooted at the Composition entry. That is, they should be the source or the target of a reference relation that traces all the way up to the root entry.

Unfortunately I have not been able to locate all the relevant passages in the FHIR specification; one place where it is spelled out is in [3.3.1 Document Content](https://build.fhir.org/documents.html#content), but it is not really clear whether this pertains to *all* bundles of type 'document' (i.e. even those that happen to be bundles with type code 'document' but are merely collections of machine-processable data without any aspirations to represent a FHIRy document).

The problem with the referencedness requirement lies in the fact that the HAPI validator employs linear search for checking the references. So, if we have to ship N bundle entries full of data to a payor, we have to include a list with N references (one for each data-bearing bundle entry). That leads to N reference searches with O(N) effort during validation, which makes the reference checking complexity effectively quadratic in the number of entries.

This easily brings even the most powerful computers to their knees. Current size contraints effectively cap the number of entries per file at roughly 25000, and the HAPI validator needs **several hours** to chew through that, even on the most powerful CPUs currently available. Without the references, validation would take less than a minute for the same file.

In our use case, data-bearing entries have no identity outside of the containing bundle file. Practically speaking they would need neither `entry.fullUrl` nor `entry.resource.id`, because their business identifiers are contained in included base64 blobs. However, presence or absence of these identifiers has no practical influence on the time needed for validation (fractions of a second even for a 1 GB file), so who cares. It's the list of references that kills the HAPI validator.

Perhaps it would be possible to fulfil the letter of the referencedness requirement by making all entries include a reference to the Composition. The HAPI validator doesn't care either way, so I don't know whether that would be valid or not. But even if it were FHIRly valid, it would be a monstrously silly workaround.

Is there a way to ditch the referencedness requirement? Perhaps by changing the bundle type to something like 'collection', or by using `contained` resources?

P.S.: for the moment we are using a workaround that cuts the time for validation from hours to less than a minute, but it's a hack, and we currently don't have the resources to fix the HAPI validator. What I'm mostly concerned about is the question how the specifications (profiles) need to be changed in order to avoid the problem I described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (i.e. even those that happen to be bundles with type code 'document' but are merely collections of machine-processable data without any aspirations to represent a FHIRy document)

If it is not a document, and not intended to be one, do not use the 'document' Bundle type. If you do, you would me misrepresenting the data which is what FHIR tries to avoid.
It seems like you want to send a collection of resources that are not necessarily related, so

> Is there a way to ditch the referencedness requirement? Perhaps by changing the bundle type to something like 'collection'

Yes, I would use 'collection', or maybe a 'batch/transaction' depending on what I want to tell the receiver to do with the data.

Comment: The entries in the file **are** related in the sense that they are all prescriptions that belong to the same invoice (which is specified in an entry referenced from the Composition). Practically speaking, their belonging to the given invoice is already expressed by the fact that they are included in the same file, removing the (practical) need for a list of references. Earlier profile versions allowed multiple invoices per file, so things were somewhat different then.

Comment: It seems that most FHIR grouping/bundling constructs - e.g. List - use inclusion by reference instead of bodily inclusion. This makes a lot of sense in an online context (where the resources may be independently available via a FHIR HTTP server) but not so much in an offline context, where the data has no existence outside of the transmitted file.

Comment: 25000 items is rather a lot for an invoice... can you share an example with me so I can have a look at it? (I write the validator, and I sure didn't write it to be used with 25k resources in production). (send to grahameg at gmail. I can sign NDA if necessary)

Comment: @ Grahame: This is a monthly invoice from a billing centre to a given insurer, and it contains all prescriptions for that particular insurer dispensed by pharmacies who are customers of the centre. Hence the number 25000 is easily reached even by a small centre like ours, while bigger centres have to split their invoices into dozens or hundreds of parts with 1 GB each. See https://simplifier.net/eRezeptAbrechnungsdaten for an overview and https://simplifier.net/packages/de.gkvsv.erezeptabrechnungsdaten/1.2.0/files/561486 for the document resource that is currently in production.

Comment: I'm sending details, links to example resources and a script for generating a full-size 1 GB file via E-Mail shortly.

Comment: @ Mirjam: it seems that simply changing the bundle type from 'document' to 'collection' does indeed get rid of the referencedness requirement. Thanks for pointing out this easy solution!

Comment: @ Grahame: the advantages of FHIR - especially the ability to validate directly against the specification (profile) - are even more important for the big transfers between billing centres and insurers than they are for the daily work in a practice or pharmacy, because the amounts of money involved (and hence the risks) are so much bigger.

Answer (score 0):

The documents page says:

> The document bundle SHALL include only:
>
> 1. The Composition resource, and any resources directly or indirectly (e.g. recursively) referenced from it
> 2. A Binary resource containing a stylesheet (as described below)
> 3. Provenance Resources that have a target of Composition or another resource included in the document

A document is a frozen set of content intended as an attested, human-readable, frozen set of content.  If that's not what you need, then use a different Bundle type.  However, if you *do* need the 'document' type, that doesn't mean that systems should necessarily validate all requirements at runtime

Comment: The resource in question is definitely not a human-readable document; it's just a megaton of data. The profile specifying it as a bundle of type 'document' is, however, a nation-wide standard that everyone has to comply with for now. If our working group can assemble well-funded technical arguments then we may be able to influence what the next iteration of the standard/profile looks like. The takeaway for now is two-fold: review the bundle type (e.g. change to 'collection') and get rid of the reference list that no longer serves any practical purpose.

Comment: Be that as it may, it is not entirely clear whether all bundles with type 'document' must conform to the specification of 'FHIR Document', or whether FHIR documents represent merely a restricted subset among all the bundles of type 'document'. Elsewhere in the specification the scope of 'document' is much wider. Also, one must not forget that the resource in question effectively replaces a paper document (a paper prescription), or rather a carton or lorry full of them. This may explain the choice made by the profile authors.

Comment: All Bundles of type 'document' are expected to follow the rules for FHIR Document.  That doesn't mean they have to be 'clinical' documents, but they definitely must start with CapabilityStatement, have all resources related by references, and be renderable as human-readable documents.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think you meant 'Composition' instead of 'CapabilityStatement', though. ;-)

Comment: Indeed I did :)